# datepicker inside TextBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textbox, jquery-ui-datepicker

I downloaded a particular datepicker (http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/).

I tested it with this line of code:

```
<input class="fieldset__input js__datepicker picker__input" type="text" readonly="" id="tbDate" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-readonly="false" >
```

This works, but i don't know how i can add the datepicker inside a TextBox element.
I tried it like this but it isnt working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {

            $("#" + '<%=tbDate.ClientID%>').datepicker();
        });
    });
</script>
 <asp:TextBox ID="tbDate" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Can You please explain to me how i should call this datepicker?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any luck with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {    
            $(".someUniqueClass").datepicker();
        });
    });
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbDate" runat="server" class="someUniqueClass" ></asp:TextBox>
```

I changed the selector to use the class...

You may also try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {    
            $(".someUniqueClass").pickadate();
        });
    });
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbDate" runat="server" class="someUniqueClass" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Or this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {    
            $("#" + '<%=tbDate.ClientID%>').pickadate();
        });
    });
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbDate" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

I'm not familiar with that date picker, but it looks like you are using the wrong event name.